Calculating terms of a power series of a function
Define a function $f:(-\infty,8^{1/5}) \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{8-x^5}} $. Consider its Taylor expansion at $x=0$, $$f(x)  = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n \frac{x^n}{n!}$$ where $a_n = f^{(n)}(0)$ is the nth derivative of $f$ evaluated at $x=0$. I am trying to compute $a_{15}$ and $a_{17}$; however, the traditional method to compute the derivative of $f$ to this order is time-consuming. Is there an alternate method which is faster?

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

How about using binomial series $(1+y)^{-1/2}=1-\frac12y-\frac12\left(-\frac32\right)y^2/2!-\frac12\left(-\frac32\right)\left(-\frac52\right)y^3/3!\cdots?$   See right away $a_{17}=0$

Do you know binomial expansion for negative powers @DWdd ?

@J.W.Tanner thank you very much, i didnt know the binomial series. I understand it now.

Hint:
Use the binomial series:
$(1+y)^{-1/2}=1-\frac12y-\frac12\left(-\frac32\right)y^2/2!-\frac12\left(-\frac32\right)\left(-\frac52\right)y^3/3!\cdots$
